# Executors recursive with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, executors

I want to apply ExecutorService for recursive read path from url in the format given,I had difficulty trying to recall recursive
**getRecursive(element.attr("abs:href"), level);**

```
public class NewClass {

    static String levels[] = {"div.col-md-9 li a", "div#sidebar ul li a"};

    private void getRecursive(String href,int level) {

        if (level > levels.length - 1) {
            return;
        }

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(href).get();
            Elements elements = doc.select(levels[level]);

            level++;
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            for (final Element element : elements) {
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!element.attr("href").isEmpty()) {
                            String links = "";
                            links += element.attr("abs:href") + "\n";
                            System.out.println(links);
                            getRecursive(element.attr("abs:href"), level);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass().getRecursive("http://www.java2s.com/", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `level` variable has to be `final` in order to access it in the `run()` method. In any case, your not using `ExecutorService` correctly, your program is not limited to `5` threads because you're creating a new `ExecutorService` every time you call the `getRecursive(...)` method.

To use the same `ExecutorService` for every recursion, you can do something like this:

```
public class NewClass { 

    static String levels[] = { "div.col-md-9 li a", "div#sidebar ul li a" };    
    static String links = "";   

    private void getRecursive(String href, int level, final ExecutorService executor) { 

        if (level > levels.length - 1) {    
            return; 
        }   

        Document doc;   
        try {   
            doc = Jsoup.connect(href).get();    
            Elements elements = doc.select(levels[level]);  
            final int flevel = ++level; 
            for (final Element element : elements) {    
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {   
                    @Override   
                    public void run() { 
                        if (!element.attr("href").isEmpty()) {  
                            links += element.attr("abs:href") + "\n";   
                            System.out.println(links);  
                            getRecursive(element.attr("abs:href"), flevel, executor);   
                        }   
                    }   
                }); 
            }   
        } catch (IOException e1) {  
            e1.printStackTrace();   
        }   
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); 
        new NewClass().getRecursive("http://www.java2s.com/", 0, executor); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: I want to ask you how to check if the work has been completed. I tried to apply executor.isTerminated() in main.But Fail

Comment: @MaTâm  `isTerminated()` returns `true` only if you've called `shutdown()` and all submited tasks have finished. When you call `shutdown()` the `ExecutorService` won't accept new tacks but will finish all the submited tasks.

Comment: @MaTâm It will be best to use the `awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method, this method blocks (stop the execution of code on the thread that calls it) untill all the submited tasks finish. Here is how you can use it `awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)`

Comment: If levels.length = 1, the rule enforcer works well,but If levels.length>1 will appear error : Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-138" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Comment: I think the termination of executor with recursion is a difficult question and I have not seen it exist on stackoverflow, so I thought I would make an easier question all need it later.Please continue to discuss this issue with me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512762/how-is-an-executor-termination-recursion-in-java