# How is an executor termination recursion in java?

Tags: java, recursion, executorservice, executor, termination

This is a program that reads information site for previous format it uses recursion and executor.It works fine,my problem is to test whether the program is completed and success notification.

```
public class NewClass { 

    static String levels[] = { "div.col-md-9 li a", "div#sidebar ul li a" };    
    static String links = "";   

    private void getRecursive(String href, int level, final ExecutorService executor) { 

        if (level > levels.length - 1) {    
            return; 
        }   

        Document doc;   
        try {   
            doc = Jsoup.connect(href).get();    
            Elements elements = doc.select(levels[level]);  
            final int flevel = ++level; 
            for (final Element element : elements) {    
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {   
                    @Override   
                    public void run() { 
                        if (!element.attr("href").isEmpty()) {  
                            links += element.attr("abs:href") + "\n";   
                            System.out.println(links);  
                            getRecursive(element.attr("abs:href"), flevel, executor);   
                        }   
                    }   
                }); 
            }   
        } catch (IOException e1) {  
            e1.printStackTrace();   
        }   
    }
```

If **levels.length = 1**, the rule enforcer works well,but If **levels.length>1** will appear error : Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-138" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        new NewClass().getRecursive("http://www.java2s.com/", 0, executor);
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        if (executor.isTerminated()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't submit any new tasks after you shutdown the `ExecutorService`, the recursion seems to stop after you've processed all the levels (you don't submit any new tasks after that), you can do something like this:

```
if (level > levels.length - 1) {    
    executor.shutdown();
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @titus.the program works perfectly,thanks to you I've understood more about executor,recursion and how to control them.

Comment: @titus Won't this still have a chance of failing with the same error? Since `execute` is called in a loop, if one of those newly submitted tasks is run before the loop finishes and calls `shutdown`, then we'd go back to the loop and try to call `execute` and it would fail. Not sure if it will happen in practice (since it depends on the number of times `execute` is called, the length of time it takes for each task to run, and the thread scheduler, but I think it's theoretically possible...)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're calling `executor.execute` after calling `executor.shutdown()`. The `awaitTermination` method only waits for tasks that were submitted before `shutdown` was called.

Here's why this is happening:

- Let's say the program starts on thread `main`.
- The first call to `executor.execute` is on `main`.
- Suppose the executor now runs on `thread-pool-1`, it also calls `executor.execute`.
- But before those new tasks execute, we jump back onto `main` and call `executor.shutdown`.
- The executor might start executing tasks again, maybe on `thread-pool-2` this time, and it tries to call `executor.execute`. However, `executor.shutdown()` has already been called, so a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` is thrown.

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. Using an executor might be overkill in this instance; just doing it single threaded will probably be sufficient.
2. It may be possible to refactor the code so that the last `executor.execute` can call `executor.shutdown`. However, if there isn't a distinct last call, this won't be possible.
3. If you absolutely need to do this off the main thread, you could perform the entire recursive call in its own thread:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
           executor.execute(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   NewClass.getRecursive("http://www.java2s.com/", 0);
               }
           });
           executor.shutdown();
           executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
           if (executor.isTerminated()) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   private static class NewClass {

       static String levels[] = { "div.col-md-9 li a", "div#sidebar ul li a" };
       static String links = "";

       private static void getRecursive(String href, int level) {

           if (level > levels.length - 1) {
               return;
           }

           Document doc;
           try {
               doc = Jsoup.connect(href).get();
               Elements elements = doc.select(levels[level]);
               final int flevel = ++level;
               for (final Element element : elements) {
                   if (!element.attr("href").isEmpty()) {
                       links += element.attr("abs:href") + "\n";
                       System.out.println(links);
                       getRecursive(element.attr("abs:href"), flevel);
                   }
               }
           }
           catch (IOException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The example you've posted is single single threaded, in his example, he always calls the `getRecursive(....)` on a new thread.

Comment: Your suggestion of two very precious to me, I will study them carefully.Thank you very much

Comment: @Titus yes, my single-threaded example is one of three possible solutions to the problem. A multithreaded solution feels a bit like over engineering in this case, but I don't know what the OP's needs are.