# Iterative algorithm for generating compositions

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I've implemented an algorithm, which writes out all possible combinations of X items in Y boxes (in combinatorics, I believe they're called compositions). I wrote this algorithm using a recursive function, because it's easier to keep track of the current box we're putting the items in, and the remaining number of items.
This algorithm is giving me the following output (for 4 boxes, and 3 items):

> [3, 0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], ..., [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 3]

As you can imagine, the number of compositions grows quite a bit for large X and Y. Since I don't care about the order compositions come in, I wanted to parallelise the further calculations, but I can't do that on a recursive function (I've tried doing it by saving the state of the recursion, but that's rather messy, and despite the fact that it works, it's really slow). 
So, I was wondering if it's possible to re-write the same function iteratively (using `for` loops), so that I can parallelise it. (One thing to keep in mind is, that optimisation is also important, because I need to run the function for large X and Y) My recursive function is written below:

```
public void charArrangements (int boxes, int items, String strBuild) {
        if (boxes > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= items; i++) {
                String ss = strBuild + (items - i) + ";";
                charArrangements(boxes - 1, i, ss);
            }
        }
        else {
            String ss = strBuild + items;
            List<Integer> charArrangement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            charArrangement = Stream.of(ss.split(";")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

            doCalculations(charArrangement);
        }
}
```

Comment: Assuming fw is a file, you're very likely to be bound by IO performance, so parallelising may not help very much.

Comment: That's not the point. I was testing the function by writing it out. I shouldn't be writing it out anyway, because for big X and Y, the files become humongous, and I don't have enough space for that. In reality, there would be calculations in that try/catch block.

Comment: Fair enough!  Though can you not just parallelise the loop on the initial call to `charArrangements`?  i.e. you say you have 11 items, so that means you could have 11 threads, each handling a different initial value of `items`.

Comment: That seems similar to zmbq's answer, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about that. If I did it on the initial call like you said, I'd get [2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2] for 2 boxes, 2 items, [1, 0], [0, 1]  for 2 boxes, 1 item, and [0, 0] for 2 boxes, 0 items. If I'm interested in 2 boxes and 2 items, then 1, or 0 items are of no concern to me. Which means, I'd need to somehow parallelise it on lower levels, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you need to have all of the results in the output?  Or could you get by with an iterator that spits them out one at a time?  Or something that randomly selects one of the results uniformly at random?  Or just the total number of possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to be able to access the state of the accumulating solution more directly; for example, being able to save and restore it without having to rebuild it each time. One way to achieve this can be to use lexicographic generation.

I would suggest first creating the number partition without any zeros and then adding the zeros and using a known, simple algorithm for next lexicographic permutation, which you could easily lookup online. Here's an example ordering for 5 items into 7 boxes:

```
Order partitions in decreasing order by number of parts

[0,0,1,1,1,1,1] -> generate all lexicographic permutations
[0,0,0,1,1,1,2] -> generate all lexicographic permutations
[0,0,0,0,1,2,2] -> ...
```

Here's what I came up with for an algorithm for a reversed next lexicographic partition of equal size, perhaps it can be improved or corrected (we reverse it so we can start with the lowest ranking permutation in the next step):

```
(0) The first partition is either k (n/k)'s if k divides n,
    or (remainder of n/k) (n/k + 1)'s and (k - remainder of n/k)'s (n/k)'s
    to their left.

(1) Find the leftmost part, l, greater than 1

(2) If l is the rightmost part, we're done.
    Otherwise, decrement l and increment the leftmost part, r,
      right of l that is lower than its right neighbour.
      If r is not found, increment the rightmost part and
        set the rest of the partition according to
        instruction (0), where k and n now would be 
        (k - 1) and (n - rightmost part), respectively.

[0,0,0,0,1,2,2] -> generate all lexicographic permutations
[0,0,0,0,1,1,3] -> ...
etc.
```

Comment: Isn't there a mistake there? For example, if I have 5 items in 2 boxes.. (k-1) (n/(k-1))'s gives me one 5, therefore [0,5]. That means l=5, and it is also the rightmost part, so we finish. So, where are all the other possible partitions, such as [1, 4] and [2, 3]?

Comment: @NoelAramis you're right, that was a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I believe I corrected it now.

Comment: There is still something that I don't quite understand - Instruction (2). First of all, is r actually l+1, and it exists only if r+1 exists? And second thing: If r exists, how does the recursion continue? Even if r doesn't exist, calling the instruction(0) with (k-1) and (n-rightmost part) gives a smaller array, which (I assume) is returned as a result to the level above and appended to the rightmost part. But again, how does the recursion continue? If I start with k=2, n=5, my first result is [2,3]. Then I get through instruction(2), where r isn't found, and get [1,4]. What about [0,5]?

Comment: @NoelAramis the algorithm is for next lexicographic partition of equal size, meaning equal number of parts. [2,3] => l is 2; r is not found so we increment the rightmost part and set *the rest of the partition*, where n is now 5 - 4 = 1 and k is 2 - 1 = 1, so [1,4], done. [5] would be a different starting (and finishing) point for the partition/s of 5 into one part, to which you could then append as many zeros as you like and go to the next step of enumerating the lexicographic permutations.

Comment: Yes, but suppose your starting point is [3,4]. l is 3, r isn't found, and we get [2,5]. Doesn't the algorithm terminate here and we never get [1,6], or am I wrong? Here, [1,6] should still be a partition of 7 into 2 parts.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this . lets try

```
public void charArrangements (int boxes, int balls, String strBuild) {
    for(int j=boxes;j>1;j--){
        for (int i = 0; i <= balls; i++) {
            String ss = strBuild + (balls - i) + ";";
            }
    }
}
```

after this you can do logic which you had in else clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke recursive call in a different thread and `join` current thread to it, e.g.:

```
public void charArrangements (int boxes, int balls, String strBuild) {
    if (boxes > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= balls; i++) {
            String ss = strBuild + (balls - i) + ";";
            final int count = i;
            try{
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        charArrangements(boxes - 1, count, ss);
                    }
                };
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();
                t.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        String ss = strBuild + balls;
        List<Integer> charArrangement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        charArrangement = Stream.of(ss.split(";")).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

P.S. Removed file writing part.

Comment: I've tried that now and it works, but it actually takes longer. I believe that's because the calculation on a single iteration of the recursion is really fast, so managing the threads takes more time. Ideally, I'd use one thread for doing calculations on thousands of charArrangements, but to pool them together like that, I need to go through the recursion anyway, so I'm not gaining any time.. Is there a solution?

Comment: Have a look at this example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512762/how-is-an-executor-termination-recursion-in-java), it uses executor service which is higher level abstraction of what I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

with threads it is like

```
public void charArrangements (int boxes, int balls, String strBuild) {
    ArrayList<myThread> arr=new ArrayList<>();//fill arraylist
    for(int j=boxes;j>1;j--){
        arr.get(j).start();
    }
}



//put this login in your threads run() method
public void someFunc(int balls, String strBuild)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= balls; i++) {
        String ss = strBuild + (balls - i) + ";";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you parallelize a recursive function? Use the main thread to go through the first N levels (the best N depends on your problem space), then let concurrent workers handle level N+1 and onward.

Comment: My final problem space would ultimately be 11 items in 75 boxes. By not parallelising the function it takes about 3 minutes to do 5 items in 75 boxes. The time goes up exponentially, so parallelisation is my only possibility. So, I should do the first, say N=5 levels on a single thread, and then parallelise level 6, 7, 8 and on? How do I handle N+2 and onwards? If my N+1 level is taking up all of my available threads, I can't use them on the lower levels, can I?

Comment: Each thread will handle levels N+1 until the end. As for managing worker threads, I suppose there's some sort of threadpool that you can use in Java, isn't there?

Comment: Yes, there is. Would you be able to provide some sort of pseudocode (or C# implementation, it's similar enough to Java anyway) for how to handle the first N levels with one thread and then parallelise and join?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but ugly iterative algorithm for enumerating weak k-compositions in reverse lexicographic order might look like:

```
static void weakCompositions(int n, int k, Consumer<int[]> callback) {
    assert n >= 0: n;
    assert k >= 0: k;

    if (k == 0)
        return;

    int C[], i, x;
    C = new int[k];
    C[0] = n;

    while (true) {
        callback.accept(C);

        i = k - 2;

        while (i >= 0 && C[i] == 0)
            i--;

        if (i < 0)
            break;

        C[i]--;
        x = C[k - 1] + 1;
        C[k - 1] = 0;
        C[i + 1] = x;
    }
}
```

where `n` is number of items and `k` is the number of boxes.

Not sure if it's amenable to parallelization though.

The basic idea is to find the position of the rightmost non-zero value in the prefix of the array (i.e., excluding the final entry); "transfer" 1 from that position to its immediate right; and, also into that new position, soak up all the values to its right (if there are any at all, it should simply be the last value in the array, by construction).

I believe it should be possible to keep track of the rightmost non-zero value of the prefix of the array instead of having to scan for it for each composition generated. Doing so might also make it easier to analyze the algorithm and see if it is constant amortised time.

Lastly, the [number of weak k-compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions) is given by `(n + k - 1)! / n! / (k - 1)!`. You mentioned your final problem space is 11 items in 75 boxes, which is over 21 trillion objects! Even with parallelization, that seems...formiddable. Good luck!